# How to install omsagent in ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: 20.04

I want to know, how to install omsagent in ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Vamsi

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agent-linux?tabs=shell

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.